# Getting SUID Sandbox Helper Error With WSL + Electron + Typescript on "npm start"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, npm, electron

As in title. I'm running Node v8.10.0 trying to follow this basic tutorial on Electron + Typescript:
https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript

Full error message below:

```
[699:0319/131800.461011:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without 
sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /mnt/c/Users/curio/Visual Studio Workspace/JSONDemo/JSONDemo/spectral-game/level-editor/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your NodeJS version `v8.10.0` is very old and it is incompatible with Electron `v6.0.8` which the [electron-quick-start-typescript/package.json#L23](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript/blob/275a20272bc43e6a1d6c0cfc9c339b3c46253603/package.json#L23) has.

According to the release notes of Electron `6.0.0`, `6.0.8` is compatible with NodeJS `12.4.0`.

You have to use [NodeJS `v12.4.0`](https://nodejs.org/download/release/v12.4.0/).